# Is Strimzi compatible with the azurefile AKS storage class?

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-aks, strimzi

While setting up a simple Strimzi Kafka cluster in AKS, I'm getting a problem when brokers need to delete/clean log files. The problem only occurs when using the azurefile storage class, but works fine with others.

Steps to reproduce on a cluster with 1 broker and 1 Zookeeper replica. Deleting a topic triggers the error in the broker pod. The problem also occurs when the log cleaner tries to run on a topic with the 'compact' policy.

Strimzi cluster settings

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: test-cluster
  namespace: kafka-test
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 3.0.0
    replicas: 1
    listeners:
      - name: plain
        port: 9092
        type: internal
        tls: false
      - name: tls
        port: 9093
        type: internal
        tls: true
      - name: external
        port: 9094
        type: nodeport
        tls: false
    config:
      offsets.topic.replication.factor: 1
      transaction.state.log.replication.factor: 1
      transaction.state.log.min.isr: 1
      default.replication.factor: 1
      min.insync.replicas: 1
      inter.broker.protocol.version: "3.0"
      auto.create.topics.enable: "false"
    storage:
      type: jbod
      volumes:
        - id: 0
          type: persistent-claim
          size: 2Gi
          deleteClaim: true
          class: azurefile
  zookeeper:
    replicas: 1
    storage:
      type: persistent-claim
      size: 2Gi
      deleteClaim: true
      class: azurefile
  entityOperator:
    topicOperator: {}
    userOperator: {}
```

Strimzi topic settings

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaTopic
metadata:
  name: custom-topic
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: test-cluster
spec:
  partitions: 1
  replicas: 1
```

Initial state, pods running normally with custom-topic in a ready state
[image]

After running `kubectl delete kafkatopic custom-topic` the broker pod crashes with the following error log

```
2022-07-19 10:00:16,211 ERROR Error while renaming dir for custom-topic-0 in log dir /var/lib/kafka/data-0/kafka-log0 (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel) [control-plane-kafka-request-handler-0]
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /var/lib/kafka/data-0/kafka-log0/custom-topic-0 -> /var/lib/kafka/data-0/kafka-log0/custom-topic-0.20aa2754010549d58935ea4144c2f1f6-delete
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:478)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:267)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1422)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.atomicMoveWithFallback(Utils.java:932)
        at kafka.log.Log.$anonfun$renameDir$2(Log.scala:699)
        at kafka.log.Log.renameDir(Log.scala:2487)
        at kafka.log.LogManager.asyncDelete(LogManager.scala:1036)
        at kafka.log.LogManager.$anonfun$asyncDelete$3(LogManager.scala:1071)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:437)
        at kafka.log.LogManager.$anonfun$asyncDelete$2(LogManager.scala:1069)
        at kafka.log.LogManager.$anonfun$asyncDelete$2$adapted(LogManager.scala:1067)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet$Node.foreach(HashSet.scala:435)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:361)
        at kafka.log.LogManager.asyncDelete(LogManager.scala:1067)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.stopPartitions(ReplicaManager.scala:468)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.stopReplicas(ReplicaManager.scala:405)
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handleStopReplicaRequest(KafkaApis.scala:291)
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handle(KafkaApis.scala:174)
        at kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandler.run(KafkaRequestHandler.scala:75)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

the pod never recovers from this and I have to delete/recreate the cluster. This error only seems to happen when using a Kubernetes storage class with the file.csi.azure.com provisioner. Using kubernetes.io/azure-disk or disk.csi.azure.com there is no problem. I tried creating a custom storage class with some explicit permissions set, but this didn't work either.

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: kafka-azurefile
provisioner: file.csi.azure.com
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
allowVolumeExpansion: true
mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0777
  - file_mode=0777
  - mfsymlinks
  - actimeo=30
  - uid=0
  - gid=0
parameters:
  skuName: Standard_LRS
```

Strimzi version: 0.27.1
Kubernetes version: 1.22.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka requires block storage it does not work with file storage. I think on Azure, that is normally the Azure Disk Storage. *(Also, 2Gi of storage are relatively small for Kafka. Not sure how far will you get before running out of disk space.)*

Comment: That would explain it, thanks. The 2Gi of storage was just for this test.